# Display popover with rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I try to create a popover with rails and bootstrap like this:

```
        <%= content_tag(:a, role: "button", data: {
                        content: "#{image_tag('/user.png')}",
                        toggle: "popover",
                        content: "Click here"
            }) %>
```

But somehow when I render the page is displayed like this (its not encounterd as html):

```
{:data=>{:content=>"Click here", :toggle=>"popover"}}
```

In the inspect mode the html looks like this:

```
<a>{:data=&gt;{:content=&gt;"Click here", :toggle=&gt;"popover"}}</a>
```

What do I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to add a value for your tag `<%= content_tag(:a, 'your button', role: "button", data: { content: "#{image_tag('/user.png')}", toggle: "popover", content: "Click here" }) %>`

Comment: @cristian Thank you a lot! Please write that as an answer!So that I can rate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a value for your tag (second argument):

```
<%= content_tag(:a, 'your button', role: "button", data: { content: "#{image_tag('/user.png')}", toggle: "popover", content: "Click here" }) %>
```